# bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, sequelize.js, bcrypt

While installing bcrypt I'm getting this error in my windows machine, I'm using

- node v8.9.4
- npm v5.6.0
- bcrypt v1.0.3

> C:\Users\user\Desktop\mysql_node_api\register_login\register_login>npm
>   install bcrypt --save > bcrypt@1.0.3 install
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\mysql_node_api\register_login\regis
>   ter_login\node_modules\bcrypt > node-pre-gyp install
>   --fallback-to-build node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://github.com/kelektiv/node
>   .bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@8.9.4 ( node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with
>   node-gyp) gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find
>   Python executable "python", you can set the PYT HON
>       env variable. gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\n
>   pm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19) gyp
>   ERR! stack at PythonFinder.
>        (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\np m\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16) gyp
>   ERR! stack at
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_mo
>   dules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29 gyp ERR! stack at
>   FSReqWrap.oncomplete
>         (fs.js:152:21) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData
>   \Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "co nfigure" "--fallback-to-build"
>   "--module=C:\Users\user\Desktop\mysql_node_ap
>         i\register_login\register_login\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_li
>   b.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib"
>   "--module_path=C:\Users\user\Desktop\mysq
>   l_node_api\register_login\register_login\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding"
>   gyp ERR!
>         cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\mysql_node_api\register_login\register_login\
>   node_modules\bcrypt gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v
>   v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp ERR! build error node-pre-gyp ERR!
>   stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program
>         Files\nodejs\node.e xe C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\
>   node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
>   --module=C:\Users\user\Desktop\mysql_n ode_api\register_login\register_login\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib
>         .node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\user\Desktop\mysql_node_ap i\register_login\register_login\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding' (1)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.
>          (C:\Users\user\Desktop\m ysql_node_api\register_login\register_login\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\c
>   ompile.js:83:29) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
>   node-pre-gyp
>           ERR! stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/chi ld_process.js:209:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT
>   6.1.7601 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>           "C:\Users\user \Desktop\mysql_node_api\register_login\register_login\node_modules\node-pr
>   e-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\mysql_node_api\register_login\regist
>   er_login\node_modules\bcrypt
>           node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok Failed to execute
>   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\user\AppData\Roamin
>   g\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure
>           --fallbac k-to-build --module=C:\Users\user\Desktop\mysql_node_api\register_login\register _login\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\user\Desktop\mysql_node_api\register_login\register_login
>           \node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding' (1) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: node-pre-gyp install
>   --fallback-to-build npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script. npm ERR!
>
> This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log ging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run
>   can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-02-25T14_42_29_5
>   29Z-debug.log

Answer (score 10):

I also encountered this error im using node v14.x. I found out that the pre-built binaries of bcrypt v1.0.3 is not available for node v14. To fix it, I have to install a different bcrypt version.

```
npm uninstall bcrypt --save
npm install bcrypt@5 --save
```

That's it. It works now!

Comment: thanks its really work as a magic for me I am facing the same problem but your solution is magic

Answer (score 4):

Finally after many research I solve this problem. So, guys those who are facing this problem just do the below processes,

I just installed python and set the environment variables now it's working perfect for me.

- Install Python (while installing in windows you can get the option for add path in environment variables, just tick the check box or else)
- Set the path in environment variables
- Now store the downloaded python.exe file in this directory "c:\Python\27\python.exe"
- Now run this cmd in terminal `npm config set python "c:\Python\27\python.exe"`

Now do `npm install` or run your project.
I think now your problem is solved. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the installation of Python didn't solve my problem. Instead of bcrypt, I used [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) and then it works. For more details you can see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUhVaVd3uZw).