# Error during npm i : node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install, node-pre-gyp

I know i shouldn't just throw a question like this and wish i can provide more information, but i am really no idea what it is and it also my first time encounter such issue (after change to new laptop), i think currently i can only provide the error message until someone ask me to provide further info..

Below is the error show in my cmder while running npm i

```
D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaCustomerApp (Jerry-Dev2 -> origin)                    
λ npm i                                                                        

> grpc@1.10.0 install D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaCustomerApp\node_modules\grpc   
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library            

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-p
recompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.0/node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz        
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.0 and node@10.5.0 
(node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)         
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://storage.googleapis.com/
grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.0/node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz  
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.0 and node@10.5.0 
(node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)         
gypgyp  ERR! ERR!configure error                                               
configure error                                                                
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you 
can set the PYTHON env variable.                                               
 Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env varia
ble.                                                                           
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\Program File\
nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)         
     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\Program File\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node
_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)                                     
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\Program File\n
odejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)          
     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\Program File\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_
modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)                                      
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack     at D:\Program File\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29                                      
     at D:\Program File\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfi
lls.js:284:29                                                                  
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  stackstack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)        
     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)                                    
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  SystemSystem Windows_NT 10.0.16299                           
 Windows_NT 10.0.16299                                                         
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  commandcommand "D:\\Program File\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Prog
ram File\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" 
"configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=D:\\ADA\
\Projects\\foodNinjaCustomerApp\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binar
y\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--mod
ule_path=D:\\ADA\\Projects\\foodNinjaCustomerApp\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node
\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown"                                
 "D:\\Program File\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program File\\nodejs\\node_modules\\
npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build
" "--library=static_library" "--module=D:\\ADA\\Projects\\foodNinjaCustomerApp\
\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\\g
rpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=D:\\ADA\\Projects\\food
NinjaCustomerApp\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win
32-x64-unknown"                                                                
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  cwdcwd D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaCustomerApp\node_modules\grpc
 D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaCustomerApp\node_modules\grpc                        
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  node -vnode -v v10.5.0                                       
 v10.5.0                                                                       
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  node-gyp -v v3.6.2                                           
node-gyp -v v3.6.2                                                             
gyp gyp ERR! ERR!not ok                                                        
not ok                                                                         
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error                                                  
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'D:\Program File\nodejs\node.e
xe D:\Program File\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.j
s configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=D:\ADA\Projec
ts\foodNinjaCustomerApp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-wi
n32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=D:\ADA\Pro
jects\foodNinjaCustomerApp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64
-win32-x64-unknown' (1)                                                        
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\ADA\Projects\foodNi
njaCustomerApp\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:
83:29)                                                                         
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)            
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)   
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/ch
ild_process.js:248:5)                                                          
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299                                 
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program File\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\ADA\\Projec
ts\\foodNinjaCustomerApp\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\
node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"       
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaCustomerApp\node_modules\grpc   
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.5.0                                              
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39                                      
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok                                                       
Failed to execute 'D:\Program File\nodejs\node.exe D:\Program File\nodejs\node_
modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build
 --library=static_library --module=D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaCustomerApp\node_mo
dules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node 
--module_name=grpc_node --module_path=D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaCustomerApp\node
_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown' (1)        
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fs
events):                                                                       
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents
@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64
"})                                                                            

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                       
npm ERR! errno 1                                                               
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --libra
ry=static_library`                                                             
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                         
npm ERR!                                                                       
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.0 install script.                             
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional lo
gging output above.                                                            

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                           
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jerry.ho\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-29T17_22
_12_579Z-debug.log
```

I've been looking around for the same problem but i still really understand the problem and solution.  Here is the post i found:

-[bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48975021/bcrypt1-0-3-install-node-pre-gyp-install-fallback-to-build) : Don't really understand.

-[NPM Install Error - Node-Pre-Gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513644/npm-install-error-node-pre-gyp) : i tried `npm cache clean --force` and run `npm i node-gyp` again still the same erro

Additional info:

->node version: 10.5.0

->npm version: 6.1.0

->windows 10 Pro 64bit

The error caused i having error to run `ionic serve`. The error shown as below:

```
D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaClientApp (Jerry-Dev2 -> origin)
λ ionic serve
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2
    at module.exports (D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaClientApp\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaClientApp\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ADA\Projects\foodNinjaClientApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\core\bundle-components.js:6:16)
```

I really need a guide to solve the issue.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after so many attempts I resolve this issue and this issue is just becuase version mismatch of library which is reside in package.json.

I just installed python and set the environment variables now it's working perfect for me.Make sure you have installed Python 2.7.

Install Python (while installing in windows you can get the option for add path in environment variables, just tick the check box or else)

Set the path in environment variables.

For verification open the command prompt and write python command if it will not give any error then it is working fine.

Also check grpc version in package.json and update it with current version.

Remove old node_moules

now run `npm update`

Now do `npm install` or run your project. I think now your problem is solved. :-)